# TortoiseSVN slow on show modifications

Tags: performance, svn, tortoisesvn

I used to see the list of modified files in less than a few seconds using "Check for modifications" command in TortoiseSVN. But things have suddenly changed and now it's taking something like 1 or 2 minutes to show me the locally modified files.

I wonder if anybody has had the same problem and if anyone has ever managed to find a workaround to it. I am using TortoiseSVN on Windows 7. I've also got two branches of the slow trunk and both of them are working fast.

Comment: @sbi - "Check for modification" has nothing to do with the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was due to the existence of a large number of **non-versioned** log files in a temporary folder under the SVN working copy directory. I deleted them all and things got as fast as before :) It was very fool of me I hadn't noticed those files already!

Answer (score 6):

Run the cleanup command. That will adjust the file times of all your files in your working copy.

See the approach mentioned [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#detectmodification) for why that helps.

Comment: This made all difference for me. Now the question arises, if I copy a file using windows explorer, will not the file time be preserved? I obviously had a lot of files with the same timestamp...

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same symptom as the original poster: "Check for Modifications" was suddenly *much slower* for me.  But the accepted solution (a large number of non-versioned files) didn't help.

I continued searching and experimenting, and finally found another solution.  In my case, I had the "Properties" check box checked in the "Items to show" section of the "Check for Modifications" window.  Unchecking that check box sped it up by *orders of magnitude*.  I am happy again.

Comment: Yep, that brings the window up much faster.